# SSRS chart custom fromating

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to format may chart axis to have thousand separators, but using apostrophes instead of commas.

For example, with a `,` separator in the format expression `#,#0` the value `1222333` shows as `1,222,333` but my expected output is `1'222'333` should work for any range of numbers.  How can I replace the comma separator with an apostrophe?

Example 
With custom expression `#,#0`

1. `2,000`
2. `22,000`
3. `222,222,000`

Expected output

1. `2'000`
2. `22'000`
3. `222'222'000`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with the built in formatting options.

What you can do though is format your number as you require, with commas as the thousands separator, then convert the number to a string and replace the commas with apostrophes:

```
=replace(cstr(format(10000
                    ,"#,#0"
                    )
             )
        ,","
        ,"'"
        )
```

Comment: Replace is not working in chart axis custom expression is seem as a string

Comment: Is this for the vertical axis?  If so, I think what you want to do is impossible.